# Convert utf8 unicode strings to uft8 general ci in PHP not from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, unicode, utf-8

I'd like to ask you how to convert `utf8 unicode` strings to `utf8_general_ci` strings in PHP. The reason why I want to do so is because when I import Chinese/Japanese/Russian characters from CSV file in PHP, I can only get strings like `¾G¨Ø®S` ...etc. But since I set all collation to `utf8_general_ci`, I couldn't smoothly save data like `¾G¨Ø®S` to database.

Thinking of converting strings to utf8 general ci format, I'm not sure if the Collator Class is able to do so (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php)?

PS. I'm using Cakephp framework.
Thanks

Comment: Did you set as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: Hi Ranjith, I did. Actually I was using https://github.com/ockam/php-csv as a csv import module for cakephp. There are many examples in PHP-CSV. I'm pretty sure this will happen when you use characters in Hindi.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8) php library and use utf8_chr_to_unicode_style function to convert each unicode charaters to code.

Comment: Thanks Abdou! This is amazing! But will take some time for me to check it out. I will tell you the results later..

Comment: Link is now 404.